# Openssl EVP encryption/decryption not working

Tags: c, openssl

The purpose of the application is to pull the $MFT, ecnrypt it and save it on the disk. The second part of the code is decrypting it and saving it in clear form.
For some reason the decryption process is not working, I get only gibberish and apparently the same 4096 bytes repeat over and over.
I know the code is dirty, I tried to minimize it as much as possible, but if anyone spots any clear problem, please do let me know.

Thanks

```
    char publicKey[]="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"\
                 "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAy8Dbv8prpJ/0kKhlGeJY\n"\
                 "ozo2t60EG8L0561g13R29LvMR5hyvGZlGJpmn65+A4xHXInJYiPuKzrKUnApeLZ+\n"\
                 "vw1HocOAZtWK0z3r26uA8kQYOKX9Qt/DbCdvsF9wF8gRK0ptx9M6R13NvBxvVQAp\n"\
                 "fc9jB9nTzphOgM4JiEYvlV8FLhg9yZovMYd6Wwf3aoXK891VQxTr/kQYoq1Yp+68\n"\
                 "i6T4nNq7NWC+UNVjQHxNQMQMzU6lWCX8zyg3yH88OAQkUXIXKfQ+NkvYQ1cxaMoV\n"\
                 "PpY72+eVthKzpMeyHkBn7ciumk5qgLTEJAfWZpe4f4eFZj/Rc8Y8Jj2IS5kVPjUy\n"\
                 "wQIDAQAB\n"\
                 "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
rsa_pkey = createRSA(publicKey,1);
if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsa_pkey))
{
    printf("EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA: failed.\n");
    return 1;
}
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
ek = malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(pkey));

if (!EVP_SealInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), &ek, &eklen, iv, &pkey, 1))
{
    printf("EVP_SealInit: failed.\n");
}
eklen_n = htonl(eklen);

DWORD BytesWritten2;
if(WriteFile(outputMFTfile, &eklen_n, sizeof(eklen_n), &BytesWritten2, NULL))
{
    printf("Written %d bytes to the file header [EK LEN]\n",BytesWritten2);
}
if(WriteFile(outputMFTfile, ek, eklen, &BytesWritten2, NULL))
{
    printf("Written %d bytes to the file header [EK]\n",BytesWritten2);
}
if(WriteFile(outputMFTfile, iv, EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(EVP_aes_128_cbc()), &BytesWritten2, NULL))
{
    printf("Written %d bytes to the file header [IV]\n",BytesWritten2);
}

while (ReadFile(hRawDisk, FINAL_MFT_BUFFER, 4096, &bytesRead, NULL))
    {
        bytesCounter = bytesCounter+(unsigned long long)bytesRead;
        if (bytesCounter<final_length)
        {
            if (!EVP_SealUpdate(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out, FINAL_MFT_BUFFER, bytesRead))
            {
                printf("FAILED SEAL UPDATE \n");
            }
            WriteFile(outputMFTfile, buffer_out, len_out, &BytesWritten, NULL);

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!EVP_SealFinal(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out))
{
    printf("FINAL SEAL FAILED\n");
}
else
{
    DWORD BytesWritten;
    WriteFile(outputMFTfile, buffer_out, len_out, &BytesWritten, NULL);

}

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
```

The following code is used for decryption(I removed the part where I provide the private key and initialize EVP):

```
HANDLE decryptedMFTfile=CreateFile("MFT_decrypted.dat",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
DWORD BytesWritten2;
while(bytesRead>0)
{
    ReadFile(encryptedMFT,buffer,sizeof(buffer),&bytesRead,NULL);

    if (!EVP_OpenUpdate(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out, buffer, len))
    {
        printf("EVP OPEN FAILED \n");
    }
    WriteFile(decryptedMFTfile, &buffer_out, sizeof(buffer_out), &BytesWritten2, NULL);

}
```

CreateRsa code on request:

```
RSA * createRSA(unsigned char * key,int public)
{
RSA *rsa= NULL;
BIO *keybio ;
keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, -1);
if (keybio==NULL)
{
    printf( "Failed to create key BIO");
    return 0;
}
if(public)
{
    rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
}
else
{
    rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
}
if(rsa == NULL)
{
    printf( "Failed to create RSA");
}

return rsa;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post `createRSA` code ?

Comment: When calling `EVP_OpenUpdate()`, what is the value of `len`? Why not use the value of `bytesRead`?